# Laplace Equation For Infinite Plate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential, laplacian

[image: Text Book Question]

I initially put it into the form of

\begin{align}
X'' + \lambda^2 X &= 0 \\
Y'' - \lambda^2 Y &= 0
\end{align}

which has solutions

\begin{align}
X &= a_n \cos(\lambda x) + b_n \sin(\lambda x) \\
Y &= c_n \cosh(\lambda y) + d_n \sinh(\lambda y)
\end{align}

Given boundary conditions

\begin{align}
y(0) &= U_{0} \\
x(0) &= 0 \\
x(a) &= 0
\end{align}

substituting into the solutions for $X, Y$ yields $a_n = 0$, $c_n = U_{0}$ and $\lambda = n \pi/a$.

My final solution is

$$u(x,y) = 2 U_{0} \sum_{n \ge 1} b_n \sin \left(\frac{n \pi x}{a} \right) e^{-n \pi y/a}$$

So it's close...but I am not sure how to get rid of the lambda in the exponential and the additional terms of $4$ and $\pi$

Comment: You're missing a boundary condition which is required to get the final solution. I'm also not sure where the $2$ came from in your series solution. Also, the picture in the book is very unclear and doesn't really match the question.

Comment: I believe there's an error in the book with those exponents. As written, their solution doesn't even satisfy Laplace's equation. BTW, you need to treat the boundary condition at $y=0$ more carefully: $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}u(x,y) = u_0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Mattos I'm pretty sure the 4th boundary condition is given by the implicit assumption that the solution is finite over its domain, i.e. $\lim_\limits{y\to\infty} u(x,y) < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incomplete. Separation of variables gives the general solution

$$ u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)e^{-n\pi y/a} $$

The boundary condition at $y=0$ requires

$$ u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right) = u_0 $$

You need to find the Fourier series of the RHS to determine the $b_n$'s. This is given by

$$ b_n = \frac{2}{a}\int_0^a u_0 \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right) \ dx = \frac{2u_0}{n\pi}\big[1-\cos(n\pi)\big]$$

or

$$ b_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n \text{ even} \\ \dfrac{4u_0}{n\pi}, & n \text{ odd} \end{cases} $$

As for the missing constants in the exponents, I believe that's a typo in the text.

Comment: n odd / even seems to be switched

Comment: Ah, I see - I had assumed I needed to do a Fourier transform, but was not sure if I was in the right step or not, thank you very much!

Comment: As it happens, the resulting series has the explicit sum $u(x,y) = \mathrm{Im}[\tanh^{-1}(\exp[i\pi(x+iy)])]$